# Best way to take advantage of .NET 3.5

Tags: linq-to-sql, web-applications, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

I currently have an asp.net web application which is using seperate assemblies for the data access, the business logic,
entity objects, and the web user interface. The data access was created using Microsoft's Data Access Application Block
compilied as a .NET 2.0 assembly. Stored procedures were used for the actual moving of data in and out of the database
(SQL 2005).

I would like to update this application to a take advantage of the new features of .NET 3.5 such as Linq, data entities,
etc. What would be the best approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing some research about this topic and I found this article very useful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/archive/2008/05/17/why-use-the-entity-framework.aspx

Obviously, .net 3.5 has lots of new features if you compare to 2.0. one of them as you stated Linq(to SQL and to XML). which enables you to write strongly-typed language integrated queries. as you may know as well as querying your entities by using LINQ, you can query your collections and XML files.
Also you can use ADO.NET entity framework for mapping your database tables to classes. I am not sure about performance aspect. u might need to do some investigation about it.

dont forget to do your regression tests after you have developed new version of your application.

I know it is general information... I hope it helps.

Cheers